# How to get gif resource from maven

Tags: java, maven, resources, gif

I am making a Discord bot. I've had embedded images from around the internet via URLs and now I want to use locally saved images.

My problem is that I can't manage to load the resource of the gif onto the Java application.

I tried renaming them, editing the pom.xml even more, alas to no result. I tried using Files but that didn't work.

```java
File file = new File(Values.class.getClassLoader().getResource("first.gif").getFile());

System.out.println(file.exists());
System.out.println(file.getPath());

BufferedImage userThumbnailGIF = ImageIO.read(file); //this is Values.java:37
```

That is where I tried to get the file from resources, and this is my pom.xml:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>first.gif</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>first.gif</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The output on the console for the files is:

```
false
C:\Users\It%20is%20all%20ogre%20now\IdeaProjects\ToramBot\target\classes\first.gif
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at com.github.zastrixarundell.torambot.Values.setImages(Values.java:37)
    at com.github.zastrixarundell.torambot.ToramBot.main(ToramBot.java:65)
```

**Note:** my OS is Windows.

When I do navigate to that directory by hand, the file does exist.
[image: image of directory]

**Edit:** the **file** variable is also not null.

Comment: Don't read it from `File` but from `URL`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right! That's it:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)

Use Values.class.getClassLoader().getResource("first.gif") and pass it to ImageIO.read(). You could also wrap that into an InputStream.

Comment: Well, in the end, I just used it as an InputStream!